# Monitor smart power plug with Prometheus / Grafana

Tags: rest, prometheus, grafana

I barely managed to set up Prometheus & Grafana on my new Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian). Now I would like to monitor a [smart power plug with a REST API](https://api.mystrom.ch/#982cf1bb-c873-4f62-b3c2-1cdfa51e1afe). That means I could send a `curl` command and receive some data back:

```
$ curl --location --request GET '[Switch IP]/report'

{
  "power": 35.804927825927734,
  "relay": true,
  "temperature": 21.369983673095703
}
```

However I am at a loss as to how to get this data automagically queried and parsed by Prometheus. My Google Fu is failing me as all the results explain how to query Prometheus. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible approaches to make this a bit more straightforward:

- https://github.com/ricoberger/script_exporter
- https://github.com/grafana/agent/issues/1371 — discussing a possible script_exporter integration
- https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway — Prometheus’ push gateway
- https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter — Prometheus’ blackbox exporter
- https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/pushing-bash-script-result-to-prometheus-using-pushgateway-a0760cd261e — this post shows something similar

Answer (score 0):

It's non-trivial, unfortunately.

Prometheus "scrapes" HTTP endpoints and expects these to publish metrics using Prometheus' exposition format. This is a simple text format that lists metrics with their values. I was unable to find a good example.

You would need to have an "exporter" that interacts with your devices and creates metrics (in the Prometheus format) and publishes these on an HTTP endpoint (not REST just a simple text page).

Then, you'd point the Prometheus server at this exporter's endpoint and Prometheus would periodically read the metrics representing your device and enable you to interact with the results.

Comment: Thanks! Glad actually relieved to hear it's not only me. I am quite surprised that this should be such a challenge. Couldn't I write a simple Python / bash script that dumps the data into the Prometheus database somehow?

Comment: I think there are alternatives. It's not uncommon for devices to publish Prometheus metrics "out of the box". (1) Ping the myStrom folks and ask them to add a (default) `/metrics` endpoint to their API that produces device metrics for you. (2) Use one of the excellent home automation tools, e.g. https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/mystrom/. These (often, please check) integrate with Prometheus so you'd get that for all devices you add. (3) See whether someone else has written an integration that you can use (was unable to find any after a brief Google).

Comment: (4) Write a Python integration yourself **but** I recommend you use a Prometheus SDK (https://github.com/prometheus/client_python). It would be a fun project and you'd learn some good stuff.